# How to export WordprocessingML to PDF with docx4j and send to response object?

Tags: docx4j

i'm using docx4j lib to work with docx file. And want to export a pdf file when user browse my jsp page.

i've got WordprocessingML from word file. But don't know how to convert it to pdf file and response (as use can download pdf file)

any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

It’s all there in the sample code provided with the library. docx4j converts content to PDF using Apache FOP. There’s an example class demonstrating this functionality in the “samples” folder here:

https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/samples/docx4j/org/docx4j/samples/ConvertOutPDF.java